# Prolog: How to break a piece of chocolate into its pieces

Tags: prolog, logic

I've got the following task to do:

Given a rectangular chocolate bar, consisting of m x n small rectangles, and the wish of breaking it into its parts. At each step you can only pick one piece and break it either along any of its vertical lines or along its horizontal lines. How should you break the chocolate bar using the minimum number of steps?

I know you need exactly m x n - 1 steps to break the chocolate bar, but I'm asked to do it "the CS way:"

Define a predicate which selects the minimum number of steps among all alternative possibilities to break the chocolate bar into pieces. Construct a straucture on an additional argument position, which tells you where and how to break the bar and what to do with the resulting two pieces.

My thoughts: after breaking the piece of chocolate once, you have the choice of breaking it either on its vertical or its horizontal lines. So this is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
break_chocolate(Horizontal, Vertical, Minimum) :-
break_horizontal(Horizontal, Vertical, Min1),
break_vertical(Horizontal, Vertical, Min2),
Minimum is min(Min1, Min2).

break_horizontal(0,0,_).
break_vertical(0,0,_).

break_horizontal(0, V, Min) :-
    V > 0,
    break_horizontal(0, V, Min).

break_horizontal(H, V, Min) :-
    H1 is H-1,
    Min1 is Min + 1,
    break_vertical(H1, V, Min1).

break_horizontal(H, V, Min) :-
    H1 is H-1,
    Min1 is Min + 1,
    break_vertical(H1, V, Min).

break_vertical(H, V, Min) :-
    V1 is V-1,
    Min1 is Min + 1,
    break_horizontal(H, V1, Min1).

break_vertical(H, V, Min) :-
    V1 is V-1,
    Min1 is Min + 1,
    break_vertical(H, V1, Min1).

break_vertical(H, 0, Min) :-
    H > 0,
    break_horizontal(H, 0, Min).
```

Could anyone help me with this one?

Comment: I forgot Prolog long ago, but I would test it on a 1x2 or on a 1x1 chocolate bar. I would suspect infinite recursion first.

Comment: "... but it doesn't work" is not good enough. What happens exactly? What do you expect to happen? Did you try debugging it yourself, and what did you find?

Comment: As @Boris has pointed out, the number of breaks is always `mn - 1` for an `n x m` bar (trivially proven by induction). So, what exactly do you want this program to do? Can you show a sample output?

Comment: I know the number of breaks is always mn - 1, but I'm asked to write a program for it. Well, and the thing is - nothing happens. When i run my code, Prolog just freezes and my computer crashes, so I'm not able to do any debugging at all.

Comment: A couple of issues with your code. Firstly, there's an infinite recursion with `break_horizontal(0, V, Min) :- V > 0, break_horizontal(0, V, Min).` Fix that, and your program might stop crashing. Secondly, the logic overall only assumes you're breaking an `X` by `Y` piece into two pieces of `X-1` by `Y` and `1` by `Y`, or `X` by `Y-1` and `X` by `1` in many places. It might ignore some of the cases where you're not just breaking off one row or column.

Comment: Your original problem statement also says, *Construct a structure on an additional argument position, which tells you where and how to break the bar...* and your program doesn't do that at all. If you look at all the hints in the answers, this will take you a large step in the right direction. Once you have your structure, and write a predicate to traverse it and give every possible traversal, then you can add the counting back in if desired (which will always result in `mn - 1`).

Comment: Your base cases don't provide a minimum value (they yield `_` instead) and seem indicate the minimum size of a dimension is `0` rather than `1`. Those will likely give you trouble.

Comment: The `break_vertical(H1, V, Min)` in your third `break_horizontal/3` clause should be, `break_vertical(H1, V, Min`)`. There are other issues as well, such as `Min1 is Min + 1` is attempted before the value of `Min` is known, which yields an error. And your logical structure will count some break scenarios multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but should push you towards the right direction:

First an observation: every time you cut a chocolate bar, you end up with **exactly one more** pieces than you had before. So, actually, there is no "minimal" number of breaks you can have; you start with 1 piece (the whole bar), and you end up with `m * n` pieces, so you always have exactly `m * n - 1` breaks. So either you have misunderstood your problem statement, or somehow misrepresented it in your question.

Second: once you break into two pieces, you will have to break **each of the two** in the same way that you have broken the previous one. One way to program that would be with a recursive call. I don't see this in your program, as it stands.

Third: so do you want to report the breaks that you make? How are you going to do this?

Whether you program in Prolog, C, or JavaScript, understanding your problem is a prerequisite to finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some additional hints for representing and solving your problem.

Each break separates one piece into two pieces (see Boris' second hint). You can, therefore, think of the collection of breaks as a binary tree of breaks which has the following characteristics:

- The root node of the tree has the value `M-N` (the bar is `M x N` in dimension)
- Suppose `X-Y` represents the value of any node in the tree representing a single `X` by `Y` piece that is not the single piece, `1-1`. Since the two children of the node represents the piece of dimension `X` and `Y` being broken along one dimension, then the children of `X-Y` either have the values `A-Y` and `B-Y` where `A + B = X`, or the values `X-A` and `X-B` where `A + B = Y`
- All of the leaf nodes of the tree have the value `1-1` (the smallest possible piece)

Each node of a binary tree consists of the node value, the left sub tree, and the right sub tree. An empty sub tree would have the value `nil` (or some other suitably chosen atom). A common representation of a tree would be something like, `btree(X-Y, LeftSubTree, RightSubTree)` (the term `X-Y` being the value of the top node of the tree, which in this problem, would be the dimensions of the piece in question). Using this scheme, the smallest piece of candy would be, `btree(1-1, nil, nil)`, for example. A set of breaks for a `2 x 1` candy bar would be, `btree(2-1, btree(1-1, nil, nil), btree(1-1, nil, nil))`.

You can use the CLPFD library to constrain `C #= A + B`, `A #> 0`, `B #> 0` and, to eliminate symmetrical cases, `A #=< B`.

Comment: This is a nice way to represent it. I was thinking along the lines of recording where the cut is, which is less informative than your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As an algorithm (I'm not familiar with Prolog), I can't find any different answers in the number of breaks. I've tried 4x4, and been unable to come up with an answer other than 15 (either above or below); I've tried with a 5x2 and been unable to come up with an answer other than 9.

On this basis, I would suggest the simplest possible coding method:

```
while there is more than one column:
    snap off the left-most column
    while this column has more than one square:
         snap off the top square
while the remaining column has more than one square:
    snap off the top square
```

Depending on the situation, you may wish to change one or more of: (left, column)<->(top, row), left->right, top->bottom.

Comment: Using this algorithm would make it a load easier, but it doesn't give me all alternative possibilites - and that is the point at which I'm actually struggling.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question